# Understanding LME4 random effect structures & syntax

Tags: r, lme4

Here is a problem I'm struggling to understand. Let's assume I've conducted a relatively simplistic experiment in which I have a number of subjects, and I'm recording EEG activity at the scalp, which I've divided into 9 regions. At the most basic level, I'm looking to implement a random intercept for each subject, and a random scalp region effect within subjects, while still assuming that there is a fixed effect of region - which is the predictor of interest here.

```
Response ~ region + (1|subject) + (0+region|subject)
```

My question is whether this is equivalent to:

```
Response ~ region + (1+region|subject)
```

And in turn whether that is equivalent to:

```
Response ~ region + (region|subject)
```

I'm having difficulty understanding the distinctions between these models, and which is most appropriate to use. Fitting option 3 takes a second or two, while the first takes about an hour, so clearly there is some substantial difference. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!